# Get a value from a list where a condition is true using Select()

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq, lambda

I have a JSON array where I need to get the CustomerId value from property where the CustomerId property exits for that section, I'm trying below to loop through the categories and skip the one that has no CustomerId property down its properties tree

```
var customerId = "";
    foreach (var category in JObject.Parse(someData)?["categories"])
            {
                val = category?["sections"].FirstOrDefault()
                ?["areas"]?.FirstOrDefault()
                ?["components"]?.
                ?["variables"]?.FirstOrDefault()
                ?["properties"]
                ?["customerId"]?.ToString();

                if (val == null)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    customerId = val;
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Problem is this looks inefficient (less readable) in the sense that I imagine there is a nice `.Select` that can be used to get the same result without going forEach element and check if the property is null.

Please not this is not an issue I have, this is working, I'd only like to do this in a more readable way using `Select` instead of `ForEach`.

Sample JSON Data

```
 {
      "categories": [
        {
          "identifier": "cat1",
          "sections": [
            {
              "identifier": "030615e9-67f9-43ca-a06e-194e7afadccb",
              "properties": {},
              "areas": [
                {
                  "identifier": "1206f27b-d354-4bfa-9b5e-1fe6b4f7cc83",
                  "componenets": [
                    {
                      "identifier": "49e4550f-8001-4d32-b796-a7ad4423e118",
                      "type": "Product",
                      "variables": [
                        {
                          "identifier": "0d260417-fa6d-492b-85f1-dc2565bc4805",
                          "properties": {
                        
                            "description": ""
                            
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "identifier": "cat2",
          "sections": [
            {
              "identifier": "00b5bfa6-f482-47c2-bdd7-aaac273b7772",
              "properties": {},
              "areas": [
                {
                  "identifier": "1ca9d051-5ec0-45af-84bc-561cd7620efa",
                  "componenets": [
                    {
                      "identifier": "c73b1e52-3acd-4020-8fc5-adfef7d633b4",
                      "type": "Customer",
                      "variables": [
                        {
                          "identifier": "0064e872-5c7f-4ec7-a2d6-e8b35b94bd1d",
                          "properties": {
                            "customerId": { "Text":"MainId",
"Value":"A12123"
}
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for improved efficiency or improved *readability*?  `Select()` isn't going to magically make things more efficient than your `foreach` statement because `Select()` is implemented using `foreach`.

Comment: Good question, readability, not efficiency

Comment: What is `jsonBuidler`? You haven't clarified what type this is, or what library it's from (if applicable).

Comment: Is `JObject` from JSON.NET? Can you add that as a tag on your question if that's the case?

Comment: Not relevant but updated the code, its just some parsed stuff JObject.Parse(someData)

Comment: It's actually super relevant... please also include sample JSON.

Comment: The reason I ask is because of this: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm

Comment: Fair enough, added sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach is to use `.SelectTokens` from the JSON.NET library (which it appears you are using). Assuming `parsedJson` is your parsed root object as a `JObject`:

```
var customerId = parsedJson.SelectTokens("$.categories..sections..areas..componenets[?(@.type == 'Customer')]..variables..properties.customerId.Value")
    .FirstOrDefault()?
    .ToString();
```

This essentially finds the first entry where a component has a type "Customer", and a property "customerId" and returns that customerId as a string.

Strictly speaking you don't need the query on type (`[?(@.type == 'Customer')]`) but I got the impression that's what you were going for. Without it the query would look like this:

```cs
"$.categories..sections..areas..componenets..variables..properties.customerId.Value"
```

See more about `SelectTokens` in the docs [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm).

Comment: Great that that looks like a solution to me, I do however have a last question here, the customerId has actually 2 indented properties, Text and Value, when I use your answer to get the Value property using "$.categories..sections..areas..componenets..variables..properties..customerId.Value" I do not get any results, any reason why?

Comment: @Maya I don't see that in your JSON? Also, I copied the misspelling of `componenets` from your JSON. Is this actually correctly spelled normally? If it is spelled correctly in the real JSON, you will have to update the query to match.

Comment: No no let me clarify, sorry. Your solution works perfectly with the data sample I posted above, what I'm saying is, the customerId has actually 2 more sub elements (in my real data source). I have now updated the data sample above to include the real structure.

Comment: Interesting. I tried with `$.categories..sections..areas..componenets[?(@.type == 'Customer')]..variables..properties.customerId.Value` using the data you provided above, and I got "A12123"

Comment: I tried this now too (with only with 1 dot after properties and 1 dot after customerId) and still null, but with the previous case where customerId has the value directly it works well with your solution.

Comment: Can you double-check the spelling of each part of the query and compare it to your _actual JSON_. I feel there must either be a difference in the hierarchy or the spelling.

Comment: [This code](https://pastebin.com/LKtPBdE0) works for me and prints "A12123". All I have done to your JSON is minify it and replace " with \" so that it can be used as a C# string literal. To me this seems to indicate that your actual JSON and the JSON you have provided above is somehow different.

Comment: Oh now I figured out why, the actual contents of the customerId node is ANOTHER JSON format (Text and Value are written as JSON string inside the customerId property) so now I guess I need to SelectToken the results of the first SelectToken

Comment: Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same logic as in you question, the code below is what you can use.

First you iterate over all the `categories` where you `select` the `customerId` field from.
This will result in a list of customerIds where some are `null` and some might have a value.

The next `SingleOrDefault` takes the first item from that list which does have a value. This will be your `string customerId`.

Note: When there are no customerId's in your json, the `customerId` will be `null`.
If you want to throw an exception instead of working with null, you can use `First()` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.

```cs
var customerId = JObject.Parse(someData)?["categories"]
                .Select(category => category?["sections"].FirstOrDefault()
                    ?["areas"]?.FirstOrDefault()?["components"]
                    ?["variables"]?.FirstOrDefault()
                    ?["properties"]
                    ?["customerId"]?.ToString())
                .SingleoOrDefault(customerId => customerId != null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an optimized version:

```
var pJson = JObject.Parse(someData);
JToken? customerToken = pJson.SelectToken($"$..customerId");
var customerId = customerToken?.ToString();
```

Comment: If there's no conflicts in OP's JSON (i.e. customerId in a different place) then this is a very good and clean option. +1

Comment: there would be a conflict as customerId exists elsewhere in json for a different purpose, however +1

Answer (score 0):

I would first parse the JSON to list of objects and the use the Linq to fetch the list of CusomerIds where it is not null.

```
List<T> arrayItems = jsonBuidler?["categories"].ReadFromJson<List<T>>();
List<string> customerIds = arrayItems
   .Where(_ => CustomerId != null)
   .Select(_ => _.CustomerId);
```